# ignore slicer value for only on column

Tags: powerbi, slicers, drillthrough

I have a table where it show nr of clients per practitioners. and a slicer from a Date table.

THis is the table i want to drill through IAPT Clients to another table ( see below ) and be able to see the Cient ID and All Sessions and Eligible Session ( i have measure for these 2 )

The problem is that when i drill through i don't see only 3 client ID's because my other 2 measure have ALL function to ignore the Slicer selection because some sessions are in the past and i want to count them all.

So how can i see only those 3 Client ID's but also counting all the sessions from the past ?

All Client Eligible Sessions IAPT = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('All Sessions IAPT'[revreviewID]),'All Sessions IAPT'[revsupportcategory]<>BLANK(),ALL('Date'[Month],'Date'[Financial Quarter],'Date'[Financial Year]))

All Client Sessions IAPT = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('All Sessions IAPT'[revreviewID]),ALL('Date'[Financial Year],'Date'[Month],'Date'[Financial Quarter]))

Comment: [Provide Sample data and expected output](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 0):

so the issue i am facing is that when i drill through i don't see only those 4 clients, becuase i am using the ALL function to get rid of the year, quarter, month filters becasuse some session of the clients may have been in june, may or april or march and i want to count them all.

and for that reason is not showing me only 4 clients ID with their number of sessions, it shows all clients ID's

So i only want to see only those 4 clients ID's and with their number of sessions.

I have a date table ( calendar ) and the below table :

In the drill thrgouh table i have the below measure for all client sessions

All Client Sessions IAPT = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('All Sessions IAPT'[revreviewID]),ALL('Date'[Financial Year],'Date'[Month],'Date'[Financial Quarter]))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoXbk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qU09.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pWhi.png)